# What is the best way to perform value estimation on a dataset with discrete, continuous, and categorical variables?

Tags: python, statistics, regression, prediction, feature-engineering

What is the best approach to this regression problem, in terms of performance as well as accuracy? Would feature importance be helpful in this scenario? And how do I process this large range of data?

Please note that I am not an expert on any of this, so I may have bad information or theories about why things/methods don't work.

---

**The Data:** Each item has an `id` and various attributes. Most items share the same attributes, however there are a few special items with items specific attributes. An example would look something like this:

```py
item = {
  "item_id": "AMETHYST_SWORD",
  "tier_upgrades": 1,  # (0-1)
  "damage_upgrades": 15,  # (0-15)
     ...
  "stat_upgrades": 5  # (0-5)
}
```

The relationship between any attribute and the value of the item is linear; if the level of an attribute is increased, so is the value, and vise versa. However, an upgrade at level 1 is not necessarily 1/2 of the value of an upgrade at level 2; the value added for each level increase is different. The value of each upgrade is not constant between items, nor is the price of the item without upgrades. All attributes are capped at a certain integer, however it is not constant for all attributes.

As an item gets higher levels of upgrades, they are also more likely to have other high level upgrades, which is why the price starts to have a steeper slope at upgrade level 10+.

[image: linear relationship]

**Collected Data:** I've collected a bunch of data on the prices of these items with various different combinations of these upgrades. Note that, there is never going to be every single combination of each upgrade, which is why I must implement some sort of prediction into this problem.

As far as the economy & pricing goes, high tier, low drop chance items that cannot be outright bought from a shop are going to be priced based on pure demand/supply. However, middle tier items that have a certain cost to unlock/buy will usually settle for a bit over the cost to acquire.

**Some** upgrades are binary (ranges from 0 to 1). As shown below, almost all points where `tier_upgrades == 0` overlap with the bottom half of `tier_upgrades == 1`, which I think may cause problems for any type of regression.

[image: tier_upgrades vs price, showing overlapping data]

---

**Attempts made so far:** I've tried linear regression, K-Nearest Neighbor search, and attemted to make a custom algorithm (more on that below).

---

**Regression:** It works, but with a high amount of error. Due to the nature of the data I'm working with, many of the features are either a 1 or 0 and/or overlap a lot. From my understanding, this creates a lot of noise in the model and degrades the accuracy of it. I'm also unsure of how well it would scale to multiple items, since each is valued independent of each other. Aside from that, in theory, regression should work because different attributes affect the value of an item linearly.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn import linear_model

x = df.drop("id", axis=1).drop("adj_price", axis=1)
y = df.drop("id", axis=1)["adj_price"]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=69)

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x, y)

y_pred = regr.predict(x_test)
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
mae = np.mean(np.absolute(y_pred - y_test))
print(f"RMSE: {rmse} MAE: {mae}")
```

---

**K-Nearest Neighbors:** This has also worked, but not all the time. Sometimes I run into issues where I don't have enough data for one item, which then forces it to choose a very different item, throwing off the value completely. In addition, there are some performance concerns here, as it is quite slow to generate an outcome. This example is written in JS, using the [nearest-neighbor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nearest-neighbor) package. Note: The price is not included in the item object, however I add it when I collect data, as it is the price that gets paid for the item. The price is only used to find the value after the fact, it is not accounted for in the KNN search, which is why it is not in `fields`.

```js
const nn = require("nearest-neighbor");

var items = [
  {
    item_id: "AMETHYST_SWORD",
    tier_upgrades: 1,
    damage_upgrades: 15,
    stat_upgrades: 5,
    price: 1800000
  },
  {
    item_id: "AMETHYST_SWORD",
    tier_upgrades: 0,
    damage_upgrades: 0,
    stat_upgrades: 0,
    price: 1000000
  },
  {
    item_id: "AMETHYST_SWORD",
    tier_upgrades: 0,
    damage_upgrades: 8,
    stat_upgrades: 2,
    price: 1400000
  },
];
 
var query = {
  item_id: "AMETHYST_SWORD",
  tier_upgrades: 1,
  damage_upgrades: 10,
  stat_upgrades: 3
};

var fields = [
  { name: "item_id", measure: nn.comparisonMethods.word },
  { name: "tier_upgrades", measure: nn.comparisonMethods.number },
  { name: "damage_upgrades", measure: nn.comparisonMethods.number },
  { name: "stat_upgrades", measure: nn.comparisonMethods.number },
];
 
nn.findMostSimilar(query, items, fields, function(nearestNeighbor, probability) {
  console.log(query);
  console.log(nearestNeighbor);
  console.log(probability);
});
```

---

**Averaged distributions:** Below is a box chart showing the distribution of prices for each level of `damage_upgrades`. This algorithm will find the average price where the `attribute == item[attribute]` for each attribute, and then find the mean. This is a relatively fast way to calculate the value, much faster than using a KNN. However, there is often too big of a spread in a given distribution, which increases the error. Another problem with this is if there is not an equal(ish) distribution of items in each set, it also increases the error. However, the main problem is that items with max upgrades except for a few will be placed in the same set, further disrupting the average, because there is a spread in the value of items. An example:

```py
low_value = {
  item_id: "AMETHYST_SWORD",
  tier_upgrades: 0,
  damage_upgrades: 1,
  stat_upgrades: 0,
  price: 1_100_000
}
# May be placed in the same set as a high value item:
high_value = {
  item_id: "AMETHYST_SWORD",
  tier_upgrades: 0,
  damage_upgrades: 15,
  stat_upgrades: 5,
  price: 1_700_000
}
# This spread in each set is responsible for any inaccuracies in the prediction, because the algorithm does not take into account any other attributes/upgrades.
```

[image: damage_upgrades price distribution]

Here is the Python code for this algorithm. `df` is a regular dataframe with the `item_id`, `price`, and the attributes.

```py
total = 0
features = {
 'tier_upgrades': 1,
 'damage_upgrades': 15,
 'stat_upgrades': 5,
}
for f in features:
  a = df[df[f] == features[f]]
  avg_price = np.mean(a["adj_price"])
  total += avg_price

print("Estimated value:", total / len(features))
```

If anyone has any ideas, please, let me know!

Comment: To build a good model of something, you want to try to understand the thing better. What kind of items are you trying to model the price of? How is their price set in the first place? Are you sure that the attributes you have access to are the ONLY attributes that contribute to price? Or are there some other factors (ex. special abilities associated with weapons or something) that could affect the price?

Modeling is an art more than an exact science. You can only get so far by simply trying all the tools and seeing what sticks.

Comment: I do understand the way items are priced; the game's economy is not very complex. The prices I collect are the prices that players pay for the items when buying them through an auction house. The prices of these items are always going to fluctuate a bit throughout daily cycles/updates/new metas/etc. As far as price factors go, it's going to be the item attributes only. The price is really just two components; the base price + the value of upgrades.

Comment: Upgrades seems like categorical variables to me. Did you try coding them? Usually with categories, you can't have them be numbers cause it doesn't make sense.

https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/spss/faq/coding-systems-for-categorical-variables-in-regression-analysis-2/

This means that every upgrade tier will be its own variable.

Comment: @RamiAwar I’m not sure that they are categorical. They are given as levels and I did not code them. It’s like enchantment levels in Minecraft.

Comment: I guess this question will have more attention at SE's Stats community (https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are the prices of items deterministic (fixed by the logic of the game) or instead driven by market factors? E.g.  "an upgrade at level 1 is not necessarily 1/2 of the value of an upgrade at level 2; the value added for each level increase is different." Is this defined within the logic of the game, or is this an observable behavior in market demand across a large number of players? In essence, the question is whether you are trying to model the perceived, flexible value assigned to an item by a user, or to model the explicit value function used for pricing by the game itself.

Comment: @DerekG Observable market behavior. The goal is to predict the current market value of an item at a given time (for simplicity, we can ignore the fact that prices change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For modeling right-skewed targets such as prices I'd try other distributions than Gaussian, like gamma or log-normal.
2. The algo can be made less restrictive. GBDTs offer best trade-off in terms of accuracy for such tabular data, and should be able to capture some non-linearities. They even accept categorical variables as numerical vectors (label encoder). XGBoost has more APIs, but LightGBM is more accurate and faster.
3. You may use a submodel to try to predict the binary feature  ("probability of tier upgrades") - predictions from a classifier can improve the main model compared to using the binary feature as it is (smooth predictor with no missings vs. discrete with missings).
4. You can improve model accuracy on small datasets by using cross-validation with a relatively large number of folds (20 or more), which saves more data for training.
5. Try to stay within python for all ML tasks, this is by far the most appropriate language (and yes, you can later easily host python models in production).

Answer (score 0):

I would say use logistic regression.

1. For the categorical variables convert them into [dummy variables, aka one hot encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). You can use scikit for this or google it to learn a bit more about the concept.
2. For the discrete variables I would say use a bootstrap method to estimate the mean.  Also you could use the standard deviation of the mean of the sampling distribution, the distribution built using the bootstrap method, as another regressor.  For that matter you could use the median. You may be able to use those values directly.  Note you'd have one regressor for each tier.  Perhaps you could use some pooling method to reduce the number of regressors.  Some method such as principal components analysis could help you reduce your dimensionality.
3. Depending on how rigorous you want to be you could also run some regression diagnostics as well.

When training don't forget to use cross validation and perhaps a "leave one out" method as well.

Comment: How would I do logistic regression if my Y variable is not binary categorical?